# display the selected posts of an authorized user

Tags: django

how to get the selected tasks of an authorized user correctly
now

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user_info = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='userInfo')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

class Favourite(models.Model):
    task_id = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='favourites',name='taskId')
    user_info = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='userInfo')
```

views.py

class FavouriteUserView(generics.ListAPIView):

```
serializer_class = FavouriteReceivingSerializer
pagination_class = MyCursorPagination
permission_classes = [IsAuthor]


def get_queryset(self):
    return Favourite.objects.filter(userInfo=self.request.user)
```

urls.py

```
path('user/<int:pk>/favourites/', FavouriteUserView.as_view()),
```

how to get favorite posts without sending int:id
without int:id  "detail": "Not found."

Comment: Remove the `<int:pk>` part... You already fetch the `Favourite`s of the logged in user.

Comment: wow, thanks, I tried to remove it before, there was a mistake, somehow strange, thanks for the help for the second time :)